# $index inside ng-model is not printing index in blade template

Tags: angularjs, laravel-blade

I am using **angular js** in blade template. I used ng-repeat to populate a form using data from `$http`.

When i inspect html then i get

```
ng-model="newProp[$index].display_name"
```

but i want like

```
ng-model="newProp[0].display_name"
```

I mean I want value of $index. It is printing index value when i print like `@{{ $index }}`  but inside ng-model it is printing as it is. I want  integerd so that i can send them back in server.

Plese help

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="erp in eachRoleProperties">
   <label for="" class="col-sm-8 control-label">@{{erp.display_name}} @{{$index}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-4"> 
  <select ng-model="newProp[$index].access">
     <option value="1">Yes</option>
     <option value="0">No</option>
  </select> 
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="@{{erp.display_name}}" ng-model="newProp[$index].display_name">
<input type="hidden" value="@{{erp.db_name}}" ng-model="newProp[$index].db_name">
</div>
```

Comment: can anyone figure out what is problem ?

Comment: can you give the line of ng-repeat

Comment: I do not get what do u want. First line is ng-repaet see

Comment: just use like ng-click="send($index)", $index will be 0 inside send function.

Comment: I can not use ng-click as i mentioned that {{ $index }}  is showing correct value. But when i use inside ng-model it is showing as it is

Comment: actually $scope.newProp  is showing undefined if you are saying so.